# Rapid ORM for Painless ASP.NET MVC Prototyping on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, orm

What is a good ORM to use for rapid prototyping without the hurt?

I've used LINQ-to-SQL with great success, but I always end up building a whole repository layer around it (and everything that entails) so I don't have to put "Insert/Update" and mapping logic in my controllers. If I want to add a column, I have to write migrations and update interfaces and repositories.

I'd like something that *just works*. db4o is a good candidate, but I've always had gripes with the lack of proper data paging and the cringing primary key support. So let's narrow it down to a SQL-based solution that works with SQL Server.

Which ORM can build a relational SQL database with the least amount of configuration or code?

Comment: I've generally found that more configuration = more control over the structure of the database generated. Going with auto configuration may work for what you need, but I've found I always end up writing configuration as I want to control the structure.

Comment: if you really decided to "SQL Server only" - then go with L2S. Less abstraction levels = less overall complication. If you tend to "build the right way" - go with EF CodeFirst or NHibernate (with FluentNHibernate and Loquacious Configuration).

Comment: Not sure why this was community-wiki'ed. This is a real problem I had a and the answers gave me excellent direction for my requirements (Entity Framework Code-First). Thanks, guys.

Comment: Update: EF4 Code First can't update schema. Fluent NHibernate with a unit-of-work and repository pattern works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) as it is really quick to pick up and the fluent configuration is nice.

Comment: This looks really promising. I've always shied away from NHibernate due to the spaghetti mapping XML.

Comment: If you go with the default conventions, which are quite sensible, you can auto map which makes it really quick. Like you I was never impressed by all the XML configuration needed with NHibernate.

Comment: Fluent NHibernate has changed the way I work. It is *much* better than writing repo methods for LINQ-to-SQL. Everyone using ASP.NET MVC should just use this for relational data persistence. I have a few mapping conventions to keep me sane, though, including Not.Nullable() by default and Inflector for pluralised table names.

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework is quite nice and with the latest release you get some nice features like Code First and POCO entities.

Comment: I didn't know the new Entity Framework supported this. A direct link to a good example/tutorial would be nice. I found [ScottGu's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) helpful.

Comment: The [ADO.net team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/) has some good stuff. Entity Framework 4.1 is actually really nice and easy to get going if you already have the database created.

Comment: According to the EF 4.1 release notes, "Database Schema Migration is not supported in this release...it is necessary to drop and recreate the database when the model is changed." Dropping all tables just to add a column is ridiculous.

Comment: You can mantain your schema by hand and use L2E to connect it to your program.

Comment: Fluent NHibernate won out over - cleaner entities (no DBSet<...>) and SchemaUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework / Linq2SQL have the shortest time to market.  NHibernate is a little more complicated.

I'd go with NHibernate anyway.  When things get more complicated, it gets harder slower if that makes any sense.

Comment: I tend to want to "build it right first-time", but time is a critical factor for maintaining motivation for side-projects. NHibernate has always been too much configuration. Fluent NHibernate looks nice, though.

Comment: @FreshCode, FluentNHibernate is nothing more but a convenient way to map your entities. It is no way makes your Session Management or Startup Configuration easier. But if you make these 2 things "right way" once - you'll be easily prototyping anything you want.

Comment: NH is very little config.  You can do it in code trivially in under 15 lines to set up your session factory.